# How to access first_name and last_name from belongs_to assocation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to access the first_name and last_name, two columns of an associated table, of a user by referencing the user_id column in a different table, but I don't know how to. Any tips?

Here's the view in which I try to reference it

```
<% @allhours.each do |hour| %>
  <tr id="dashfield">
  <td><%= hour.user_id %></td>
  <td><%= hour.assignment %></td>
  <td><%= hour.hours %></td>
  <td><%= hour.supervisor %></td>
  <td><%= hour.date %></td>
  <td><%=form_for(:hour_log, method: :put) do |f|%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :status, :value => 'Confirmed' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Validate'%>
  <%end%></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

I'd like to replace the "user_id", which is a number, to first_name and last_name. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have like :

```
<td><%= hour.user.first_name %></td>
<td><%= hour.user.last_name %></td>
```

Inside the controller do below to avoid `N + 1` query issues:

```
@allhours = AllHours.includes(:user)
# change the code as per your need, but idea is to include the `user`
# association in advance.
```